# SQL SERVER FIND ROWS that dont have values in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have 3 tables with one to many relation
{Downloads , TagNames,  File_Tag}

the download table Like

| ID | File | _modifieddate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FILE1.ZIP | 2/1/2023 |
| 2 | FILE2.ZIP | 3/1/2023 |
| 3 | FILE3.ZIP | 4/1/2023 |
| 4 | FILE4.ZIP | 5/1/2023 |

the TagNames table Like

| ID | TagName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | system |
| 2 | pics |
| 3 | framework |
| 4 | compressed |
| 5 | info |

the File_Tag table Like

| ID | FileID | TagID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 4 |
| 4 | 2 | 4 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 | 1 |
| 7 | 3 | 4 |
| 8 | 4 | 5 |
| 9 | 4 | 4 |

what i want all downloads table records that dont have 'pics' or 'info' tag related to it

i tried

```
select * from (
SELECT Downloads._modifieddate, Downloads.File, Downloads.ID, ROW_NUMBER() over ( ORDER BY Downloads._modifieddate DESC ) AS aa FROM
 TagNames INNER JOIN File_Tag ON TagNames.ID = File_Tag.TagID INNER JOIN  Downloads ON File_Tag.FileID = Downloads.ID WHERE  (TagNames.TagName <> 'pics' ) and (TagNames.TagName <> 'info' )) as product
```

the row_number for paging purpose
but it return file2.zip because it has another row with compressed tag
and it give me duplicates for every tag related to the file

what i expect

| ID | File | _modifieddate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | FILE1.ZIP | 2/1/2023 |
| 3 | FILE3.ZIP | 4/1/2023 |

Comment: This question has nothing at all to do with C#. The fact that you're building your app in C# is irrelevant if the question would be the same if you were using a different language. This is purely a SQL question.

Comment: What happens if it has `info` but not `pics` or vice versa

Comment: @Charlieface i don't want any

Comment: @jmcilhinney thank you for editing and make my question clear to answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is something like:

```
select * from downloads where id not in (select fileid from file_tag where tagid in (select id from TagNames where TagName in ('pics','info')))
```

Comment: sorry that didn't work for me because i enter the tagname as parameter not the id

Comment: It's trivial to modify the solution I provided. Replace "2,5" with "select id from TagNames where TagName in ('pics','info')" and now it works with tag names. Couldn't be simpler.

Comment: yes i tried your comment and it Couldn't be simpler than that. please edit your answer to be the best answer to this topic

Answer (score 3):

You need an anti-join, which in SQL is normally done using a `NOT EXISTS`

```sql
SELECT
  d.ID
  d.File
  d._modifieddate
FROM Download d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM File_Tag ft
    JOIN TagNames t ON t.ID = ft.TagID
    WHERE ft.FileID = d.ID    -- join condition
      AND t.TagName IN ('pics', 'info')
);
```

Make sure you have the join condition inside the subquery, or you will get incorrect results.

---

If you want `Downloads` which do not have *both* tags, but don't mind if they only have one, then use relational division. There are a number of ways to do this, here is a simple one:

```sql
SELECT
  d.ID
  d.File
  d._modifieddate
FROM Download d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM File_Tag ft
    JOIN TagNames t ON t.ID = ft.TagID
    WHERE ft.FileID = d.ID    -- join condition
      AND t.TagName IN ('pics', 'info')
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 2    -- NEW!!
);
```

Comment: your  code did the job but if i want to add condition for filtering the main table "download" where to put this condition

Comment: Like i want to put "(where download.size<2000 and download.finished = 'true') "

Comment: At the end `) AND d.size < 2000;`

Comment: Thanks alot i accepted this answer and it works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

```
select d.id,d.file, d.modifieddate
from downloads as d
where not exists
(
  select 1 
  from file_tag as ftag
  join TagNames as tag on ftag.tagid=tag.id
  where tag.TagName in('pics','info')and d.id=ftag.fileid
)
```

May be something like this

Comment: thak you for your answer it have the syntax that worked for me i wish i can accept two answers